# How to set frame margins in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I make a 2D game, I want to make something like there's frame margin, when plane reaches X, where its wing touches left side of window, it cant go more left.
I've done it, but it doesn't work in .exe file, only in preview in Unity
Its my code

```
if(Input.GetKey("d") && GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Statek").transform.position.x < 995)
{
    transform.Translate(Vector2.right * szybkosc);
}
```

But it works differently on different resolutions

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`transform.position.x < (Screen.width * 0.95f)` // 0.95 means that it will be 5% from right side. Play a bit with this value.